# SAP Fiori: Add SAP standard field to fiori application

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm looking for a way to include the `VBAK-SUBMI` standard field in the SAP Fiori Application "Manage Sales Orders" (F1873, [App reference](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps(%27F1873%27)/S27OP)). Within the sales order header table and the selection criteria to be precise. What would be the way to go to include a standard field within the application? The information provided here is quite thin.

I'm familiar with the exstension via "Custom Fields" application or Fiori adaption projects for custom fields and logic but I'm unsure about how to do it for standard fields. None of these approaches seems suitable for this scenario.

Could this maybe even be accomplished by using only the UI adaption? Is an extension of a cds view / odata service required?

Thanks in advance for any advice and best regards

Answer (score 0):

Fiori App "Custom Fields" is necessary if you would like to introduce custom fields into the Fiori App. But if you want to include a standard field (i.e. standard field that is already associated with the data model for the Fiori App), you should be able to do that via creation of Fiori App variant. Please check out this [link](https://learning.sap.com/learning-journeys/get-started-with-in-app-extensibility-in-sap-s-4hana/adapting-sap-fiori-uis-at-runtime_c583c4ef-276b-4ddf-b11a-5aeebf62b6c2), it provides a good explanation along with a system demo.

[Button "Adapt UI" to create Fiori App variant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1E6c.jpg)

Comment: The field isn't provided by the standard data source. So I wasn't able to do it via an App variant. But I was able to include it by creating an extension view of the CDS view accessed by the consume OData service.